# How to model a wcf security scheme

Tags: architecture, uml

What would be a good uml diagram to model a security scheme for wcf?

Is there a different type of diagram people typically use for this?

This is what I want to represent:

1) Program calls authentication service with credentials.
2) Authentication service returns security token
3) Program calls another web service and passes security token (along with the current method it is calling)
4) Web service returns data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a sequence diagram:

[image: sequence diagram]

(Created with Websequencediagrams.com, click [here](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/?lz=UHJvZ3JhbS0-QXV0aCBTdmM6IEF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSBDcmVkZW50aWFscwoAGwgtPgAvBzogU2VjdXJpdHkgVG9rZW4KAEQKbm90aGVyAEsGbWV0aG9kKAAeDiwgABwGcGFyYW1zKQoAJwsAVQtkYXRh&s=default) to edit).